# How to get connection and reading time from ClientResponse (Jersey Client)

Tags: java, jersey

How to get connection and reading time of request, that was executed in this code? Is it possible in Jersey Client?

```
WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);
WebResource.Builder builder = webResource.getRequestBuilder();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> header : headers.entrySet()) {
    builder.header(header.getKey(), header.getValue());
}

ClientResponse clientResponse = builder.get(ClientResponse.class);
```

P.s. full request time = time to install connection with external server (connection time) + time of request handling by external server (reading time)